# Trying to install github package with pip using git-bash

Tags: python, windows, git-bash

I'm trying to install: https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy. According the directions you need to run :

```
pip install git+https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy.git
```

I'm trying to do this with git-bash in win7. I've tried:

```
$ C:\\envs\\r1\\Scripts\\pip.exe install git+https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy.git
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\envs\r2\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\envs\r1\Scripts\pip.exe" install git+https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy.git'
(r2)
$ C:\\envs\\r1\\Scripts\\pip.exe "install git+https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy.git"
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\envs\r2\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\envs\r1\Scripts\pip.exe" "install git+https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy.git"'
```

How can I get the package installed?

edit:

```
(r2)
$ C:\\envs\\r1\\Scripts\\pip.exe install https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy/archive/master.zip
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\envs\r2\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\envs\r1\Scripts\pip.exe" install https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy/archive/master.zip'
(r2)
$ pip install https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy/archive/master.zip
sh: pip: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the link of `Download ZIP` from Github page and give it to pip:

```
pip install https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy/archive/master.zip
```

It should work.

Comment: Since I am not Windows user, but I can suggest you to use full path of your `pip` command like you did in your first try with `git`.

Comment: Try this `C:\\envs\\r1\\Scripts\\pip.exe install https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy/archive/master.zip`

Comment: $ pip install "https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy/archive/master.zip" worked to install without an error